# Migration error. TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object django

Tags: python, django

I have a problem, this gives me an error and I don't know why. I have tried everything including deleting the date fields even if I change it to a datetime field, i always get the same error. This is django 1.11. This happens everytime I migrate.

1.This is the traceback of the error.

```
python manage.py migrate

Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, profiles, sessions
Running migrations:
Applying profiles.0031_auto_20181107_1420...Traceback (most recent 
call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/claudia/Documents/kiboko/Aramati- 
Safaris/virtual/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/claudia/Documents/kiboko/Aramati-Safaris/virtual/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
 File "/home/claudia/Documents/kiboko/Aramati-Safaris/virtual/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
 File "/home/claudia/Documents/kiboko/Aramati-Safaris/virtual/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
 File "/home/claudia/Documents/kiboko/Aramati-Safaris/virtual/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
fake_initial=fake_initial,
 File "/home/claudia/Documents/kiboko/Aramati-Safaris/virtual/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
 File "/home/claudia/Documents/kiboko/Aramati- 
Safaris/virtual/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in 
_migrate_all_forwards
 state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, 
fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "/home/claudia/Documents/kiboko/Aramati- 
Safaris/virtual/lib/python3.5/site- 
 packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in 
apply_migration
 state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
 File "/home/claudia/Documents/kiboko/Aramati- 
Safaris/virtual/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, 
 project_state)
 File "/home/claudia/Documents/kiboko/Aramati- 
Safaris/virtual/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 86, in 
 database_forwards
 field,
  File "/home/claudia/Documents/kiboko/Aramati- 
 Safaris/virtual/lib/python3.5/site- 
 packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 414, in add_field
 definition, params = self.column_sql(model, field,         
 include_default=True)
 File "/home/claudia/Documents/kiboko/Aramati- 
 Safaris/virtual/lib/python3.5/site- 
 packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 154, in column_sql
 default_value = self.effective_default(field)
 File "/home/claudia/Documents/kiboko/Aramati- 
 Safaris/virtual/lib/python3.5/site- 
 packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 228, in 
 effective_default
  default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
 File "/home/claudia/Documents/kiboko/Aramati- 
 Safaris/virtual/lib/python3.5/site- 
  packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 766, in 
 get_db_prep_save
  prepared=False)
  File "/home/claudia/Documents/kiboko/Aramati- 
 Safaris/virtual/lib/python3.5/site- 
 packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1297, in 
  get_db_prep_value
   value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/claudia/Documents/kiboko/Aramati- 
  Safaris/virtual/lib/python3.5/site- 
  packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1292, in 
  get_prep_value
  return self.to_python(value)
   File "/home/claudia/Documents/kiboko/Aramati- 
   Safaris/virtual/lib/python3.5/site- 
  packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1254, in 
  to_python
  parsed = parse_date(value)
  File "/home/claudia/Documents/kiboko/Aramati- 
  Safaris/virtual/lib/python3.5/site- 
  packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", 
  line 61, in parse_date
  match = date_re.match(value)
  TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

2. models.py

   ```
   class GuaranteedSafaris(models.Model):

   SafariPackagesChoices=(
   ('Excursions-lakenakuru', 'Excursions-lakenakuru'),
   ('Excursions-lakenaivasha' ,'Excursions-lakenaivasha'),
   ('Excursions-nairobiexcursions' ,'Excursions-nairobiexcursions'),
   ('2dyabedare' ,'2 days - aberdare'),
   ('2dyamboseli' ,'2 days - amboseli'),
   ('2dynakuru' ,'2 days - nakuru'),
   ('2dynaivasha' ,'2 days - naivasha'),
   ('2dysweetwaters' ,'2 days - sweetwaters'),
   ('3dyamboseli' ,'3 days - amboseli'),
   ('3dymaasaimara' ,'3 days - maasaimara '),
   ('3dynakuru' ,'3 days - nakuru'),
   ('3dysamburu' ,'3 days - samburu'),
   ('3dysweetwaters' ,'3 days - sweetwaters'),
   ('4dymaranakuru' ,'4 days - maranakuru'),
   ('5dyamboseli' ,'5 days - amboseli'),

   )
    Enter_Safari_Package=models.CharField(choices= 
    SafariPackagesChoices, 
    max_length=50, default="title")

    book_before=models.DateTimeField()
    depature_date=models.DateTimeField()

    Accomodation=(
   ('bg', 'Budget'),
   ('lx','Luxury')
    )
   Accomodation=models.CharField(choices=Accomodation, max_length=20, 
   default="accomodation")

    people_booked=models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
   return self.Enter_Safari_Package
   ```

I also tried adding auto_now_add.

3. Migration: 0031_auto_20181107_1420.py

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

```
dependencies = [
    ('profiles', '0030_auto_20181107_0102'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='LowSeason',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('price1', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
            ('price2', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
            ('price3', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
            ('price4', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
            ('price5', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
            ('price6', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
            ('price7', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Packages',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('name', models.CharField(default='package name', max_length=30)),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='guaranteedsafaris',
        name='Enter_Hotel_Star',
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='guaranteedsafaris',
        name='price1',
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='guaranteedsafaris',
        name='price2',
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='guaranteedsafaris',
        name='price3',
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='guaranteedsafaris',
        name='price4',
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='guaranteedsafaris',
        name='price5',
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='guaranteedsafaris',
        name='price6',
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='guaranteedsafaris',
        name='price7',
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='guaranteedsafaris',
        name='Accomodation',
        field=models.CharField(choices=[('bg', 'Budget'), ('lx', 'Luxury')], default='accomodation', max_length=20),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='guaranteedsafaris',
        name='depature_date',
        field=models.DateField(default=0),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='guaranteedsafaris',
        name='book_before',
        field=models.DateField(default=0),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='lowseason',
        name='package',
        field=models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='profiles.Packages'),
    ),
]
```

Comment: Please show the `0031_auto_20181107_1420` migration that is failing.

Comment: @Alasdair...added

Answer (score 4):

Late reply but yes I encountered the same issue.
I removed the

> migrations folder

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_name
python manage.py migrate
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your migration is trying to add dates with `default=0`, which is not a valid date.

```
field=models.DateField(default=0),
```

You could fix the migration to use a real date, for example:

```
migrations.AddField(
    model_name='guaranteedsafaris',
    name='depature_date',
    field=models.DateField(default=date.now()),
),
```

Because you have changed the models since you created the migration, it would probably be safer to delete the migration `0031_auto_20181107_1420` (make a backup first), fix the models, then rerun `makemigrations` to create a valid migration file.

If you add `null=True` when adding a date/datetime field, then you won't have to specify a default. Otherwise, you will have to specify a default either in your model field or in the migration.

Comment: Now it says date is not defined even after i imported datetime

Comment: To use `date.now()` you need to `from datetime import date`. However, I really think you should create a new migration file. If there are any other changes in models which are not in the migration file, then your migrations will be out of sync, which can be very tricky to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Delete Your Recent Migrations, 
Then after creating one migration add this

```
from django.utils import timezone

date_created = models.DateTimeField('date_created', default=timezone.now(), blank=False)
```